# I found the installer, but how do I find the installed software, please?

Tags: software-installation

After much searching I found the installer for software that I had downloaded.

Now that the software is installed, where is it, please?

I am brand new to Ubuntu, currently running 16.04.

Comment: are you just trying to run it or do you want to know where the files it installed are?

Comment: What is the installer named? What software were you trying to install? Please provide this information so that we can be able to help you...

Comment: I want to run the installed software. Please help me. Thank you very much. TomD

Comment: Tom, what is the name of the software program you installed? If you don't remember the name, do you remember what it's used for?

Comment: at lest give the name of the "installer" so maybe we can help

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to launch the installed software, you can search for it in your dash by clicking on this icon:

[image: Dash Icon]

And type in the name of your software, for example if you want to find the screenshot tool:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, this did not help me. There was nothing there. TomD

Comment: What's the name of the installer? Something like blahblah.deb? (Or how do you install it)

Comment: I found the installer and installed the software. Now I am trying to find the installed program. Please help me. I know nothing about Ubuntu. I am running v16.04. Thank you very much. TomD

Comment: Where did you find the installer? What's the name on it?

Comment: I will say again that I found the installer. I installed the software. I cannot find the installed software. The dash produces nothing. Please, I am new to Ubuntu 16.04 and know nothing about it. Please help me. Thank you very much. TomD

Comment: @TomD But please, tell how you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

First open the Dash by clicking on the Ubuntu icon in the top left of the screen. From here click on the A icon on the bottom of the dash which I have circled in the picture below.

On this section of the dash you can see recently used and installed applications and you can also use the search function to find applications by typing in the box at the top.

[image: Applications Dash]

In practice using the search function should work in the main dash menu to find applications but I have noticed in 16.04 it doesn't always work as intended but you can always search for applications in the applications dash.